# if statements with 2 conditions

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am really confused why my script always give error result
I want to make '*if section*' with *multiple conditions*

like this

```
string kalimatsql2 = "SELECT ID FROM Questions WHERE (content = '" + var + "'" + " && Quiz_ID = '" + idQuiz + "')";
```

I already tried to change place single quote, change `=` to `==`, ommited `()`, dll
but still give error

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(content = 'test2' && Quiz_ID = '6')'.

---

**Update**

```
string kalimatsql2 = "SELECT ID FROM Questions WHERE (content = '" + dataDel + "'" + " AND Quiz_ID = " + idQuiz + ")";
int idQuestion = sqlReader(kalimatsql2);
```

and this is code for sqlReader function

```
private int sqlReader( string kalimatSql)
    {
        Global.dbCon.Open();
        List<int> idQuestions = new List<int>();
        Global.reader = Global.riyeder(kalimatSql);
        if (Global.reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (Global.reader.Read())
            {
                int idQuestion = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0));

                idQuestions.Add(idQuestion);
            }
        }
        Global.dbCon.Close();
        foreach (int id in idQuestions) {
          return id;
        }
        return (idQuestions.Count > 0) ? idQuestions[0] : -1;
    }
```

i used microsoft access as database

Comment: `var` is a keyword in C#. choose another word.

Comment: Obligatory link [bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) - please use parametrized queries.

Comment: To be precise `var` is [Contextual keyword in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/the35c6y.aspx), so it is syntactically ok to use `string var ="test2"`... But it is better use readable names (maybe "contextId" in this case) than keywords that *could* be used as variable name (including `@class` cases).

Comment: yeah, i already changed it...thanks for remembering me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to be mixing LINQ and SQL.

Replace `&&` with `AND`.

And you may also have to remove the single apostrophes from around idQuiz, if it's actually a number and not a string.

Also, we can't see the rest of your code, but you'll want to look into parameterzing your queries instead of concatenating them into one string. It's safer, and easier to read and maintain.

---

This is on-the-fly, so there may be some syntax errors. It doesn't follow your example exactly - I'm not sure what kind of logic you have in the `Global` class.

```
private int GetQuestionIds(string content, int quizId)
{
    List<int> idQuestions = new List<int>();

    string query
        = "SELECT ID FROM Questions WHERE (content = @content AND Quiz_ID = @quizId)";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", content);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quizId", quizId);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int idQuestion = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0));

                    idQuestions.Add(idQuestion);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    return idQuestions.Any() ? idQuestions.First() : -1;
}
```

You can find more info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: it's working now....i a few times get suggested to use parameterizing queries in my another question, i try to learn it from many link in internet but it's make me more confused...can u provide simple example  how to use parameter queries by this case, because i think this case still not complicated